# Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Now I am trying to write an andorid application. And see the below error:

http://k1310.hizliresim.com/1g/l/tpvwu.png

this is main code:

```
package com.hayat.goz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Teste_Basla_1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.teste_basla_1);
         setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        final Button teste_basla = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

         teste_basla .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent a = new Intent(Teste_Basla_1.this, Gorme_testi_1.class);

                    startActivity(a);

                    finish();

                }});        

    }

    @Override  
    public void onBackPressed() {

           Intent a = new Intent(Teste_Basla_1.this, MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(a);

               finish();

    }    




}
```

This is XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/uyarii">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:background="@drawable/testebaslaacilis"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think the images in my application are not small enough to parse. I can't scale them down with PhotoShop. I should solve this problem with coding, but I don't know how I can do this.

Can you give me some ideas? Thank you all...

Comment: could you at least post some of your code that causes the exception ?

Comment: I edited my question, do you have any idea?

Comment: Post the stack trace here. Don't give a link of a pic to that.

Comment: If your getting an outOfMemory error it means you have too many bitmaps loaded or that the fact that the bitmap is too large. View this to help you out: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Thank you ChallengeAccepted. But I dont know how to use this code. Can you give some detail about it. I didn't understand clearly.

Comment: This is unfortunately a common trouble of some android devices. Their heap sizes are small. What is the size of the bitmap? Have you ever tried some cleanup of the memory card, if using a real device (not emulator) ?

Comment: We got this error in a real device Galaxy Note 2, Galaxy S3, and HTC One, and so on :) The max size of a bitmat is about 25KB ...

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your bitmap size is too large for your device heap size.  See android how to [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: minhaz, thank you your answer, but I couldn't understand where I have to write this code? How do I use it?

Comment: You can not do it from XML. Write code to load bitmap them set it to button, or in background. Check the link for how to load bitmap from resource.

Comment: Can you describe it in more detaily, I dont understand... minhaz

Answer (score 0):

See if the following will help.

http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2012/09/bitmap-how-to-scale-down-image-for.html